# Identification of a jellyfish-like, shapeless sea-creature from India

Tags: sea, animal-identification, india

Photographed off the Western coast of India, Goa, to be precise. Not even sure this is a creature since I've never seen anything like it. It appeared to move by shooting tiny jets of water from its tentacle like thingies. It looks a bit like a jellyfish but without the typical shape expected.

Update: No larger animals around, but there were people fishing. Just off the water's edge. Also, no, I don't actually frequent the place so I can't be sure it's not part of the native fauna. Size: Perhaps two adult hand spans long.

[image: the sea creature]

Comment: How big?  It's really hard for us to understand what we're looking at.

Comment: Average adult handspan isn't really a good figure - women and mens hand averages differ and there is no real good info for that - so maybe, what 40cm? 50cm?

Comment: I think giving adult hand spans are a good figure for estimating size, we all have them, and while they vary a bit, [Hands are a recognized unit of measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_(unit))

Comment: I am unable to view your picture, but it sounds like a salp.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salp.  If so, please reply and I'll make it an answer.

Comment: I dont think its a salp. Going by images on Google they appear to have this translucence that the creature certainly didnt have. This is actually a screenshot from a video: hence the poor quality. Is there any way to upload a video here?

Comment: The tentacles (well, the whole thing appears to be a mass of intertwined tentacles) also appeared to have this tubular quality--not sure if this is apparent from the pic.

Comment: If someone has time, you can search through [species-identification.org](http://www.species-identification.org).  They have a nice list of marine species to go through.

Comment: Are you sure it was propelling itself?  And not just being pushed around by currents and bubbles?  Otherwise I would suspect it is an egg mass by something like a sea slug.

Comment: I would suggest posting the image and associated date and location to inaturalist.org as an observation in order to have a better chance at getting an identification.

Comment: When I was in Florida snorkeling i accidentally hit some jellyfish this looks similar to the result but only bigger.

Comment: I had followed up @SimonKingston's suggestion and posted it on inaturalist.org. Someone identified it as a Portuguese Man o War, but it doesn't seem to have the bluish tinge or the body.

Comment: looks like some kind of sea slug to me

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to tell from the poor photo, but I suspect that it is a member of the [Tunicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunicate), a class of marine animals that includes things like sea-squirts.

More specifically I would guess that it is a member of the [Pyrosomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrosome), which are more commonly found in warm waters, such as are found off Goa. Pyrosomes are actually colonial organisms composed of large number of individual pyrosomes living as a free-floating colony. They resemble a tube and can move by jetting water out of the tube through co-ordinated beating of cilia from members of the colony.

It could also be a [Salp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salp), which are similar to pyrosomes, but I think more commonly seen in non-tropical waters.